# Searching words in sentences in R

Tags: regex, r

I'd like to ask you for an advice with the following stuff. I have a data frame:

```
reviews <- data.frame(value = c("Product was received in excellent condition. Made with high quality materials. Very Good product",
                            "Inexpensive. An improvement over integrated graphics.",
                            "I love that product so excite. I will order again if I need more .",
                            "Excellent card, great graphics."),
                            user = c(1,2,3,4),
                            Review_Id = c("101968","101968","210546","112546"))
```

Then I have a topics from each of these sentences mentioned above:

```
topics <- data.frame(topic = c("product","condition","materials","product","integrated graphics","product","card","graphics"),
                 user = c(1,1,1,1,2,3,4,4), Review_Id = c("101968","101968","101968","101968","101968","210546","112546","112546"))
```

and I need to find original sentence where particular topic appears if I know user and Review_Id for sentences and also topics. Then write this sentence into column review.

Desired output should looks like following.

```
            topic      user    Review_Id                                   review
            product       1    101968     Product was received in excellent condition.
            condition     1    101968     Product was received in excellent condition.
            materials     1    101968                Made with high quality materials.
            product       1    101968                               Very Good product
  integrated graphics     2    101968         An improvement over integrated graphics.
            product       3    210546                   I love that product so excite.
               card       4    112546                  Excellent card, great graphics.
            graphics      4    112546                  Excellent card, great graphics.
```

Any advice or approach will be very appreciated. Thanks a lot in forward.

Comment: Have you tried `merge`? i.e. `merge(topics, reviews)`

Comment: Is it normal in `topics` that the same Review_Id is linked to two different users? Otherwise you can try `merge.data.frame(x = topics, y = reviews, by = c("Review_Id"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)`, or `merge.data.frame(x = topics, y = reviews, by = c("Review_Id","user"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)` once you fix the double user issue

Comment: Yes, I did. When I use merge then I have every sentences in one row but I need to have only sentence that covers particular topic.

Comment: Yes, the same Review_Id can be linked to two different users. The problem is that I need to have only sentence contained particular topic. Any thoughts on that? Desired output is what I need to have.

Comment: Assuming you add `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in the reviews dataframe, the following code return a logical vector, giving you all sentences of the first review containing the first topic: `grepl(topics$topic[1], strsplit(reviews$value[1], '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]])`. The rest should be straightforward.

Comment: Yes, this is what I need Patrick. And how could I extract particular sentence according to logic value generated by grepl?

Comment: If `l` is the logical value from above, you can use `strsplit(reviews$value[1], '.', fixed = TRUE)[[1]][l]` to extract it... but perhaps you should read some beginners tutorial about the R language

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
merge.data.frame(x = topics, y = reviews, by = c("Review_Id"), all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, this is what I need to use before some smart regex for particular sentence extraction containing topic.

Comment: REVIEW: Please try to pay attention on the quality of your posts.